# Non-homogeneous Partial Differential Equation with trigonometric coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a general method to determine an analytic particular solution of the equation
$$
-2(12+x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+4\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=\cos x?
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$-2(12+x)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+4\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}=\cos x$$
Rewrite it as a first order differential equation
$$-2(12+x)p+4\frac {dp}{dx}=\cos x$$
$$(12+x)p-2p'=-\frac {\cos x}2$$

Where $p=\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}$

Not sure it can be integrated with elementary functions

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: you're welcomed @IsaacTorres